# compressed string storage

Tags: c++, algorithm, string, data-structures, compression

Lets say I have many objects containing strings of non-trivial length (around ~3-4kb). The strings are all different from each other yet at the same time contain lots of common parts/subsequences. On average maybe 80-90% of any individual string is contained withing the others as well. Is there an easy way to automatically exploit this huge redundancy for compressing the data?
Ideally the solution would be C++ and transparent for the user (i.e. I can use it as if I was accessing a regular read only const std::string but instead reading from compressed storage).

Comment: How do the strings come to have common sub-sequences.  Is this due to repeated edits or coincidence of the data?

Comment: Imagine static HTML without support for CSS. You have lots of redundant html and only very few changing parts containing the actual information.

Comment: 1GB of ram will hold on the order of 100,000 uncompressed blobs sized 3-4KB.  do you really need it to fit in less?

Comment: Yup. I'm dealing with >= 500.000 and that is only part of the data (in a 32bit application...).

Answer (score 3):

Algorithmically, [Lempel–Ziv–Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) with one dictionary for all objects/strings might be a good start.

Comment: If a lot of strings are dynamically created over time, this dictionary will grow big. So in the end, it may be a simpler and better idea to just LZW compress the strings separately.

Comment: There will be very few strings created once the initial batch has been loaded, so I wouldn't expect a problem there...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) implementation is not hard, Also there are zip algorithms in languages (like C# and java) and you can use them.

Also If you sure 80-90% are repeated in all, create a dictionary of all words, then for each string store the position of dictionary word, means have a bit array of big size (10000 i.e) and mark the related position `bits[i]` to `1` if a `words[i]` exists in the current string. think each word length is 5 character then the abbreviation takes around 1/5 size.

Answer (score 2):

If the common parts of the strings are common because they are composed from other strings, then you might get some traction by using the [stlport](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) `rope` class, which looks for all the world like a std::string, but uses substring tree representation with copy on write that makes them both very space efficient (common substrings are shared) and very good at inserts and deletes (log(n))

When to use rope:

- you are making a template engine.  document instances are made from a template by substituting varying data in the template, and then cached for future uses.  Parts that are common to templates and instances are stored only once and shared across instances, inserts and deletes are cheap.

When not to use rope:

- you are loading many documents from outside the domain of your application (from disk, or over a network) and using them without modification.  rope doesn't share strings if they are not copied from one rope to another.  If you can afford to do the work to find the common substrings, rope can still be used to improve your final representations.

Comment: I think it has more than copy on write. I think the data is stored in a tree of strings, not in a contiguous memory zone.

Comment: It is copy-on-write combined with an ability to prepend to strings at the same algorithmic cost as appending to them.

Comment: I think I fit your second case: My strings aren't controlled by me and I get them from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Saeed mentioned, a simple Huffman coding will perform well here.

There is no need in dictionary, if the common words are known apriori (you've mentioned that it's a HTML). Just precompute a huffman table using statistical data from many HTML files (Note that you can encode whole tag by a single symbol, and you can have as many symbols as you want).